# Meaning of 有難 with missing ending

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, adjectives

Context: the manager of a boxing gym is arguing with a strong but problematic boy (問題児, he is arrogant and often violently beats other trainees) named Kamishiro and his trainer-sister that train in the gym. It is not clear (at least to me) if he doesn't want them in his gym anymore, but he says that his gym won't support them in their next match:

> じゃ今夜の試合は神奈ジム【オレら】の支援抜きでな
> キミ達２人で勝手にしたまえ
> これ以上はつき合いきれんよ

In the end, the manager and other guys from the gym show up in the locker room the night of the match, but Kamishiro doesn't look happy to see them:

> Manager: おちょくるのも大概にしろよ……  神代オオ
>
> Kamishiro: **有難**メーワクな支援　拒否るのにどこがおちょくってるって？

I understand that the boy is rejecting their support, but what exactly 有難 means here? Why is it used without い or く ending? I think the missing ending should be く, so my translation attempt is:

> I am **thankfully** rejecting your annoying support, in which way am I
> making fun of you?

Is it correct? [Here you can see the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INtk7.jpg) where they first argue and [here the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iYG9.jpg) with the sentence in question. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of a set phrase, 有難【ありがた】迷惑【めいわく】.  I suspect the shift in spelling from kanji to kana might have tripped you up.  The base meaning is something that seems welcome on the surface (the 有難【ありがた】 portion), but is actually a bother (the 迷惑【めいわく】 portion).

Relevant entries at:

- [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%9C%89%E9%9B%A3%E8%BF%B7%E6%83%91)
- [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%9C%89%E9%9B%A3%E8%BF%B7%E6%83%91-428217)

Comment: "I suspect the shift in spelling from kanji to kana might have tripped you up." ---> Exactly! Thank you for your answer!